# Laravel add http to urls

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a helper in Laravel 5.0 that automatically adds http to a url without it? This is similar to codeigniter's `prep_url` that could be found [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

Comment: I have a question to this please help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52983585/how-can-i-use-prep-url-from-codeidniter-inside-my-view-in-laravel thank you!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No but you can add it yourself. In your `composer.json` file add a files key under autoload and point it your helper file e.g.

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
}
```

Then create `app/helpers.php` with the code (lifted from https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/master/system/helpers/url_helper.php):

```
<?php

if ( ! function_exists('prep_url'))
{
    /**
     * Prep URL
     *
     * Simply adds the http:// part if no scheme is included
     *
     * @param   string  the URL
     * @return  string
     */
    function prep_url($str = '')
    {
        if ($str === 'http://' OR $str === '')
        {
            return '';
        }
        $url = parse_url($str);
        if ( ! $url OR ! isset($url['scheme']))
        {
            return 'http://'.$str;
        }
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Now you have `prep_url` globally accessible! Don't forget to run a `composer dump-autoload` too.

Comment: How can i use it inside my view?