# Redirect to external website in Laravel without adding http(s)://

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

My web app needs to redirect user to an external website using

```
redirect()->away($url).
```

However, this won't work if url does not contain **"http://"** or **"https://"**. Because the url is user defined, I don't think it's a good way to manually add **"http://"** or **"https://"**. Is there any way in Laravel that can be used to redirect user to external website without need to add **"http(s)://"**?

Comment: You can add this if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696818

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in Laravel that will force the `$url` passed to `away()` to be an external url. Using `away()` is so Laravel doesn't force it to be an internal url.

You can use `parse_url` to check if the HOST portion exists. If it does, it is an absolute URL and will redirect as you expect. If it doesn't, add a '//' to the beginning of the redirect url, so it will redirect away.

```
redirect()->away((is_null(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)) ? '//' : '').$url);
```

Note, check the HOST, and not the SCHEME. If the user enters `//google.com', this is correct and will redirect as expected, but the scheme is empty.

Or, as @Thomas suggests, use validation to force the user to enter an absolute url.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, force the user to enter it with a simple regex validation rule: `'url' => 'regex:#^https?://#'`.