# How can I use "prep_url" from codeigniter inside my View in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, http, web, view

I add the function "prep_url" from codeigniter to my laravel project like here:

[Laravel add http to urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696818/laravel-add-http-to-urls)

If I do it in my Controller like this:

```
$website = example.com;
$url = prep_url($website);
```

and then in my view I can do it like this:

```
{{$url}}
```

it shows me this: http://example.com

so everything works :)

but I have a problem

I have the table users and there all users have a website

in my controller I do it like this:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->get();
return view('user/einzelansicht' ['user' => $user] );
```

and in my view I can show my user with

```
{{$user[1]->name}}
{{$user[1]->website}}
```

how can I use prep_url here?

because I already did this in my view:

```
{{prep_url($user[1]->website);}}
```

but it tells me semicolons are not allowed and without the semicolon it does not work

then I tried in my controller this:

```
$website = $user->website;
$url = prep_url($website);
```

but this doesn't work too

so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your "website" attribute is not a string.

Try

```php
prep_url(json_encode($u[1]->website));
```

Comment: I think the use of the rethoric question makes the answer less readable and also puts it at risk for being mistaken for something which should be a comment instead of an answer. Please rephrase into a more assertive answer.